# How to pass a state to open 2nd Material UI tab when a Link is clicked in a React Next js App

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I have a link in a menu which looks like this:

```
 <ListItem button component="a" href="/messages" onClick={(e) => handleClick}> 
  <ListItemText primary="Sent" />
</ListItem>
```

`/messages` route has two tabs using Material ui. Tab 1 shows `inbox` and Tab 2 shows `sent`.

The `sent` tab is shown when `tabState` in `/messages` is set to `2`

When the list item is clicked, I want the `tabState` in /messages to be 2. Right now, it is just set to 1 on load.

```
const [tabState, setTabState] = useState(1);
```

I need to probably use useEffect to set tabState to a value stored in storage like cookie. I know I can do this using cookie and just do

```
const [tabState, setTabState] = useState(cookies.messageTabState);
```

But I am asking here if there is an easier way to do this without cookies like pass something from the list item (which is a menu item of a sidebar menu).

My `handleClick` function does nothing because I dont know how to get it to set state on the page its going to link to.

note: I dont use React router because Next js has a router.

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox for this?

Comment: @bertdida Sure, let me work on making one. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use props to pass data from one page to another  or redux to mainatin state.